# React-Hook-Form Styling Multiple Error Messages

Tags: reactjs, forms, error-handling, react-hooks, react-hook-form

May I know if it is possible to style two error messages separately for react-hook-form?

```
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Email"
        name="email"
        {...register("email", {
          required: "Email is required",
          pattern: {
            value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
            message: "Email is invalid"
          }
        })}
      />
      <ErrorMessage
      errors={errors}
      name="email"
      render={({ message }) => <p className="Emailerrormsg"><ErrorIcon className='Emailerror'/> {message} </p>}
     />
```

In my code above, I have the error message for required and another message if the input fields fails to meet the pattern. May I know how can I style of these messages differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to handle the error message logic yourself.

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-matsumoto-tl25o

You can update the style by checking the error message type